# Windows 8 NTFS errors only when on adapter

Tags: ntfs, windows-8, power-supply-unit, asus

We have a very strange error with a brand new ASUS Notebook S550CA, + Windows 8 64 bits Single language + 500 GB Hitach HDD (type: HTS545050A7E380).

- if the laptop is running on **battery** power, the system runs perfectly fine
- if the laptop is connected via the **power adapter** the system randomly shows NTFS system file errors, sometimes followed by a BSOD.

**Additional information**

- A full chkdsk was performed on all drives and no errors were shown.
- TuneUps software was installed to test the entire drives for errors. No errors were found
- Legal version of Microsoft Office installed
- Fully license McAffee antivirus installed
- No other software installed
- All latest Windows Updates Installed
- All laptop drives are up-to-date
- Many NTFS issues can be found on the internet but so far haven't located any NTFS error that is related to the power source used.

Where should we continue to search for what causes the problem. As noted, it only occurs when an external power source is used. On battery power the laptop runs perfect.

Comment: -1 because you didn't bother reading the help pages which clearly detail what is on and off-topic on this website.

Comment: Not sure why this is off-topic as the help pages clearly states "Server and Workstation operating systems, hardware, and software" and this is a laptop used by teachers at a professional language center and we want to prevent that all teachers that are going to upgrade their laptops run into the same issue

Comment: In any normal professional setting this would be sent RTM or you would utilize your support contract.

Comment: Return merchandise authorization not RTM

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to return merchandise authorization (RMA) this laptop. Normally you can do this by contacting your representative that was assigned to your support contract. If you do not have a support contract you can contact Asus through http://support.asus.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's overvolting when connected to AC power, probably because of a bad battery or circuit switcher. You can't fix this on your own, RMA it.